# Delphi to ASM - how would object creation look like in ASM?

Tags: delphi, assembly, reverse-engineering

I have a object in delphi that looks like:

```
  object DXDraw: TDXDraw
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 640
    Height = 360
    AutoInitialize = True
    AutoSize = False
    Display.BitCount = 16
    Display.FixedBitCount = True
    Display.FixedRatio = True
    Display.FixedSize = False
    Options = [doFullScreen, doAllowReboot, doWaitVBlank, doHardware, 
        doRetainedMode, doDrawPrimitive, doSelectDriver, doTexture, 
        doRGB, doMono]
    SurfaceHeight = 360
    OnInitialize = DXDrawInitialize
    TabOrder = 1
    Visible = False
    OnClick = LbBackScreenClick
    OnDblClick = DXDrawDblClick
    OnDragDrop = FormDragDrop
    OnDragOver = FormDragOver
    OnKeyPress = EdFocusKeyPress
    OnMouseDown = LbBackScreenMouseDown
    OnMouseMove = LbBackScreenMouseMove
    OnMouseUp = LbBackScreenMouseUp
  end
```

I am trying to figure out how this would look like in ASM.  In particular the Options.  I found the enum table for it, but it just seems to be read over.  I am interested in removing the doFullScreen flag.

Comment: In ASM you can only create objects at run-time. At delphi3000.com there used to be a simple guide describing how to do that in Delphi, but that entire site appears to be gone...

Comment: If you mean, how to remove the `doFullScreen` option from the `Options` option set at runtime, then use `DXDraw.Options := DXDraw.Options - [doFullScreen]`, otherwise I don't get your question (I haven't voted down).

Comment: @TLama: But why the ASM things, then?

Comment: @Andreas, ah, now I see, there's the `reverse-engineering` tag. So it's probably the question needed for some disassembler stuff. @Vans S, look for something like `call TCustomDXDraw.SetOptions`.

Comment: You've asked what a form definition looks like in assembler, which is a nonsense question since form definitions aren't *in* assembler. But what you really want to know, apparently, is how to remove an element from a set property in a compiled application. If *that's* what you wanted to know, then you should have *asked that*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no assembler code associated with .dfm form files. The properties in the .dfm file will be turned into a binary .dfm resource and then linked to the executable. At runtime the form persistence code loads the resource and processes its contents dynamically using RTTI.

Use a resource editor to see more. The form resources will appear under RCData | TMyForm for a form class named `TMyForm`. You can then extract the resource from the executable and save it to disk. Use the `convert` utility supplied with Delphi to convert it to text, passing `-t` to do that. Then edit the text .dfm. Then convert it back to binary using the `-b` option to convert. Then update the executable and you are done.

And @Remy points out a much simpler solution. Use a resource editor that supports Delphi .dfm files, for example [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm). That wraps up and shields you from all the details above.

Comment: Or use a resource editor that supports DFM resources, like XN Resource Editor.